# how to add scrollbar in div

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I want to add a `scrollbar` to div `id="kryesore"` in mainpage,when i try it doesn't work.Can you tell me what can i do and how can i fix it?

below 2 screenshot how it look like :
l

Answer (score 6, accepted):

change the line

```
<div id="kryesore">
```

to

```
<div id="kryesore" style="overflow-y: scroll;">
```

or you can write in your css or style tag in head as

```
#kryesore
{
   overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

working for me.

Comment: why it doesnt work for me , can you check this code in CSS : #kryesore{
overflow:scroll;
}


#header{
top:0px;
width:1023px;
position:fixed; 
overflow:auto;
height: 100px;
}

#headerLeft{
   top:0;
   position:fixed;
   left:0px;
   width:630px;
   height:100px;
}
#headerRight{
    right:0px;
 
 position:absolute;
}

#footer{
width:1023px;
position:fixed;
top:700px;
height:70px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
overflow:auto;
}


#footerleft{
      top:0;
   left:0px;
   position:absolute;
}

Comment: #footerCenter{
     
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 20%;   
    width: 310px;
    height: 119px;
}
#footerRight{top:0px;
right:104px;

position:absolute;
}

#maincontent 
{
position: fixed;
top: 100px !important;
width: 1023px;
height: 600px;
overflow: auto;
}

Comment: it due to u r making some div as fixed... u trying giving height to your div        #kryesore{ height:1000px; overflow:scroll; }

Answer (score 2):

Use `overflow` property to add scrollbar only when necessary:

```
#kryesore
{
   overflow-y:auto;
}
```

Comment: its necessary i can show you a screenshot of it , the problem is that when i wrote overflow-y:auto;  doesnt works

Comment: @Klevi: post your screenshot, and anyway, `overflow-y:scroll`, add scrollbars everytime.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `overflow-y` property by doing

```
#kryesore
{
   overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

`overflow-y` was only support from IE9 onward so if you are using an older version of IE you could just use `overflow`

```
#kryesore
{
   overflow:scroll;
}
```

Comment: overflow:scroll is same as overflow:auto . I try both of them and doesnt work in my mainpage

Comment: @Klevi Try removing `postion: fixed` from your header and footer